# Is Shopkeepers privilege a distinct thing in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, common-law, shoplifting, shopkeepers-privilege

There is s3 (criminal law act) reasonable source assistance and s24A (police and criminal evidence act) citizens arrest which seem to cover the same grounds but do shopkeepers have any distinct privileges that don’t overlap with these two powers?

Comment: Please clarify what s3 and s24a refer to. I'm assuming they're sections of an Act - but which one?

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

It is a common law [right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopkeeper%27s_privilege) exclusive to some states of the USA, now mostly supplanted by statute.